# Minhag no hair covering for Persian Jewish women?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

My sister tells me her ultra-frum married Persian grad school housemate does not cover her hair and that this is their minhag. Can someone confirm this tradition and if so what are the outer signs (if any) of Persian Jewish women's tznius?

I was under the impression for scriptural reasons (eg the hair aspect of [Yifas Toar](http://www.ybt.org/essays/rchait/yefastoar.html) a desired female captive of war) that hair (and subsequent covering) was an integral part of a woman with respect to beauty and hence modesty.

Edit: User sam closed the question for me in the comments [Heter for not Covering Hair](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/heter-for-not-covering-hair/6160#6160)

See especially the Ben Ish Hai and women's head covering http://text.rcarabbis.org/the-ben-ish-hai-and-women%E2%80%99s-hair-covering-an-interesting-case-of-censorship-by-jacob-sasson/

Comment: I never hear of a minhag but I have heard of limmud zechusim(see Shu"t Mayim Chayim-Rav Mashash

Comment: What does "how are Persian Jewish women's tznius expressed" mean? And why is that question dependent ("if so") on the truth of your sister's claim?

Comment: You could ask the same about pre-war Litvaks.

Comment: Sam, thanks .. would you perhaps please link to that (also what is a limmud zechusim - I do not know the term)

Comment: @Daniel ,see Shaloms answer,but it is best to read the teshuvah inside since it is often misqouted.http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/heter-for-not-covering-hair/6160#6160

Comment: A limmud zechus is when one goes out of one's way to justify a particular practice which seems prohibited

Comment: Thanks for all your pointers. If you write it as an answer, I can accept and credit you for it.

Comment: What I have heard from Persian friends in yeshiva is that since the law in Iran is that all women must cover their hair, it was forgotten that this is also a Jewish law, and so many women are just unaware. Remember, due to persecution it is very difficult for them to learn Torah in Iran and they unfortunately deal with ignorance.