# Hair covering in pre-war Europe

Tags: hair-covering

Did all women in pre-war Europe cover their hair? I’ve seen pictures of big rabbis' wives with no hair covering, and I heard that it wasn’t a thing in  pre-war Europe so technically it’s not really Halacha nowadays.

Comment: welcome aboard! Thanks for your question. Do you mean among those that identified as "Orthodox"? In a post-haskalah environment you can be sure that there were many things that men and women dropped. Also what's the basis to say that if people weren't strong in a certain area of halakhah at a certain place/time that the halakhah is no longer the halakhah?

Comment: Yes I mean very frum orthodox women. I just heard this was the reason that I see old women from Europe who were married to big talmidei chachamim and they didn’t cover their hair.

Comment: This is a known thing. I’m waiting for someone who knows the answer to come comment.

Comment: I have also heard something about there being places in Europe where even the most Orthodox women didn't cover their hair, but I have never seen a reliable source for it.  I don't think you can say it isn't halacha based on that though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heter for not Covering Hair](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/heter-for-not-covering-hair)

Comment: Isn't it possible that you saw a wig on the photo?

Comment: It certainly seems to have been common that many Jewish women, even in observant households stopped covering their hair in the early 20th c. I once heard (don't know if it was corroborated) that the Rav (JB Soliveitchik) was once asked about why his wife doesn't cover her hair and his answer was something to the effect that she simply didn't want to. He didn't defend, he didn't condemn it. It was just the reality of the time and *her* autonomous decision. I don't think you can learn out the propriety/impropriety or halakhic position of a Rav based on the observation of his Rebbetzin.

Comment: In Lita it was common ...Rav Schacter says some mitzvos have more mazal than others in different generations...

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27959/